How can I change the name of a network drive from CMD?
I am creating a test program which creates a volume, with the letter "S:", (which is a network folder).
To do that I'm using:
net use {driveLetter}: "{remotePath}"

The problem is that when I try to change the name, I get the error "Parameters not compatible"
This is the code I use:
// Now, set the custom name for the network drive
Process setNameProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo setNameStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = $"/C label {driveLetter}: \"{volumeName}\"",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
setNameProcess.StartInfo = setNameStartInfo;
setNameProcess.Start();
setNameProcess.WaitForExit();

string output = setNameProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show("output" + output);
string error = setNameProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show("error " + error);

// Check if the name setting operation was successful
if (setNameProcess.ExitCode == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"El nombre '{volumeName}' se estableció correctamente para la unidad de red '{driveLetter}:'.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Error al establecer el nombre '{volumeName}' para la unidad de red '{driveLetter}:'");
}


see net use /?

label doesn't do that, it just sets a volume label https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/label. Side note: why are you going to cmd to go to label, why not call label directly? Anyway, so you need FileName = "net.exe", Arguments = $"use {driverletter}: \"{path}\""

like this? FileName = "net.exe", Arguments = $@"use {driveLetter}: {volumeName}", When using that I get system error 85, the local device name is already being used

net use is used to connect a network drive. The name is defined by the server providing the share and can't be changed from the device you're connecting from.

@Stephan This is the first time I use net use commands, but I found a way with a .vbs script from 2006

Can you share? (Self-answering is allowed and even encouraged on this site) I'm curious how it works.

@Stephan done! It was very curious to find that script and see that I could even make the script itself also connect the unit but I preferred to separate it and have it only be in charge of changing the name

I found a solution by using a .vbs script based on Guy Thomas script
This is my code:
C#
// I create the network Drive
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = $"/C {command}",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

// If the creation was successful
if (process.ExitCode == 0)
{
    ProcessStartInfo cambioNombre = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
    cambioNombre.FileName = "wscript.exe"; // I launch the script
    cambioNombre.Arguments = $"\"{scriptPath}\" \"{volumeName}\"";
    cambioNombre.UseShellExecute = false;
    cambioNombre.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    Process nombre = new Process(); 
    nombre.StartInfo = cambioNombre; 
    nombre.Start(); 

    process.WaitForExit();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    MessageBox.Show($"La unidad de red '{driveLetter}:' se creó correctamente.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Error al crear la unidad de red '{driveLetter}:'");
}

script
Option Explicit

Dim strDriveLetter, strNewName
strDriveLetter = "S:"
strNewName = WScript.Arguments(0)

' Rename network drive
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter).Self.Name = strNewName

' Show confirmation message
WScript.Echo "Se ha cambiado el nombre de la unidad " & strDriveLetter & " a " & strNewName

I don't know if it is the most efficient and optimized solution but for now it does the trick, I attached an image of the final result which is the network drive with the personalized name.

